# Clear input field in svelte after form submission

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm struggling to find a way to clear form inputs after submission. I should mention that this form is in a Modal. It posts to Supabase correctly, I just can't figure out how to clear the input fields. Any ideas? I'm new to this and still learning. Thank you.

My Code:

```
<script>
const addVendorTest = async (event) => {
    const formData = new FormData(event.target)
   
    for(let field of formData){
      const[key, value] = field;
    }
<script/>

<form on:submit|preventDefault = {addVendorTest}>
<input
class="form-control"
type="text"
name="name"
value= "Test Name"
required
/>
<input
class="form-control"
type="text"
name="phone"
value= ""
required
/>
<input
class="form-control"
type="text"
 name="email"
value= ""
required
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forms have a native reset mechanism which can be triggered via the `reset()` function or a button with `type="reset"`.

One limitation is that a value set via regular Svelte properties will not be considered the default. To work around this, you can use `setAttribute` to set the default value. E.g.

```html
<script>
    const value = (node, param) => node.setAttribute('value', param);
    const addVendorTest = async (event) => {
        const formData = new FormData(event.target)
    
        // [Use formData]
        console.log([...formData]);

        event.target.reset();
    }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={addVendorTest}>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name"
           use:value={'Test Name'} required />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone"
           required />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email"
           required />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5512f5ae8bb6454f88c175829505e4d1?version=3.49.0)

Answer (score 1):

This clears the input field value:

```
const inputElement = document.querySelector(".form-control[name='name']")
inputElement.value = ""
```

Either do this for each input field separately. Or better, create a loop that goes through all input fields in your form.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value

Comment: I was trying to do this project without the use of Jquery, do you know if that is possible or have another solution? Thank you for the help.

Comment: @KyleMatthew159 That is not jQuery.

Comment: My apologies, its been a really long time. I was trying to do everything with svelte. Thank you

Comment: @KyleMatthew159 Querying the form would be acceptable for something like this, though you then should query relative to `event.target` rather than the `document`. Actually, you can do something like `Array.from(event.target)` and you will get a list of all form inputs (though this will contain buttons).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to DOM querying, you could `bind:` the values to individual variables, an array or an object. Then you can reset the state and the form will also reset accordingly.

E.g. using a dictionary object:

```html
<script>
    const valueDefaults = {
        name: "Test Name",
        phone: '',
        email: '',
    };
    let values = { ...valueDefaults };
    
    const addVendorTest = async (event) => {
        const formData = new FormData(event.target)
    
        // [Use formData]
        console.log([...formData]);

        values = { ...valueDefaults };
    }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault = {addVendorTest}>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name"
           bind:value={values.name} required />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone"
           bind:value={values.phone} required />
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email"
           bind:value={values.email} required />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/60db7d0e337c4972914491f8a64c8a23?version=3.49.0)

Comment: This is sort of how much program ran initially but I was trying to limit my use of global variables as much as possible. Some of my larger objects have many many properties...

Comment: Yes, it is quite a lot of boilerplate. (The variables are local though, they can only be accessed within the component.)